# Creating different arrays from elements

Tags: python, algorithm

```
obj = [
   {name: "obj1"},
   {name: "obj2"},
   {name: "obj3"}
]
```

I have these elements. I want to create different arrays from these elements like first array 10x obj1, second array 9x obj1 and 1 obj2, third array 8x obj1 and 2x obj2 and that goes like that. I need every possibilities like that:

```
arr1 = [
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"}
]

arr2 = [
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj2"}
]

arr3 = [
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj2"},
{name: "obj2"}
]
arr4 = [
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj2"},
{name: "obj2"},
{name: "obj2"}
]
.
.
.
```

How can I make that

Comment: It's not clear what the relationship between the input and expected output is. What is `obj3` for? Please elaborate.

Comment: I want every possible array from these 3 element obj1, obj2 and obj3. Some array that contain 2x obj1, 3x obj2, 5x obj3 or 1x obj3 and 9x obj2.

Comment: I mean All possible array

Comment: Also same amount of each element in every possible order or is the order not important?

Comment: order is not important

Comment: What do you mean by **first array 10x obj1, second array 9x obj1 and 1 obj2, third array 8x obj1 and 2x obj2 and that goes like that**. Do you wish to multiply 10 and obj1? Does that mean that obj1 is a numerical variable or a list of numerical variable? Or have you found an answer because you didn't upvote the current answer or mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools as it
obj = [
{name: "obj1"},
{name: "obj2"},
{name: "obj3"}
]

iter = it.combinations_with_replacement(obj, 10)

for i in iter:
    print(i)
```